# Styling custom Android spinner items

Tags: android, spinner, styles

I need to make the regular view and the dropdownview of a spinner show different text, so I created my own adapter for the Spinner (the adapter extends ArrayAdapter FYI). I am not interested though in changing the style of the regular view or the dropdownview in the spinner. I thought I would just use a super.getView(...) or super.getDropDownView(...) in getView and getDropDownView to get a view and set the text, but because of my design, I can't do that. So, I am trying to style my own CheckedTextView and inflate it getView/getDropDownView. 
Like I said, I want the items in the Spinner to have the same style as the regular Android spinner items would; so is there a built-in system style I can inherit in my own custom style for the CheckedTextView I am inflating? If so, what is it? I have looked through R.styles in the android documentation, but I haven't found a style that makes the CheckedTextView look like a regular CheckedTextView (no custom adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` ?

Comment: Oh, so you're saying if I simply inflate that resource, it should be styled correctly? I never thought of that.